# Spring Cloud Contract with Jersey

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I have a simple project Spring boot project. It contains one Jersey based Controller:
    @Path("persons")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class PersonsController {

```
    @GET
    public Person get() {
        return new Person("James", 20);
    }
}
```

It returns json response as expected (url: http://localhost:PORT/persons):

```
{
  "name": "James",
  "age": 20
}
```

My aim is to add Spring Cloud Contract tests for this controller. I have added all required mvn configurations, and test:

```
public class MvcTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new PersonsController());
    }
}
```

Here is contract (groovy file):
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

```
Contract.make {
    request {
        method 'GET'
        url('persons')
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body(
                "name": "James",
                "age": 20
        )
    }
}
```

When I run `mvn clean package` following error always is returned:
Failed tests:

```
  ContractVerifierTest.validate_getTest:26 expected:<[200]> but was:<[404]>
```

I believe this should be related to the ServletDispatcher as it doesn't  see Jersey's paths. The same project with replaced @Path to @RequestMapping works. However, I need to make it working with Jersey.
Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the section about jaxrs  support? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.x/spring-cloud-contract.html#_jax_rs_support. Here you have an example how you can use it https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/1.0.x/spring-cloud-contract-tools/spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin/src/test/resources/functionalTest/sampleJerseyProject